# Connect to database with PDO using a custom function

Tags: php, pdo, scope, database-connection, custom-function

I have a function called: `table()`.

I can't connect to the database by PDO if I've written the PDO connection outside of the function, like this:

```
include_once("server.inc");
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $username, $password); 
function table()
{
    $sql="select * FROM d1" ;
    $result = $connect->query($sql) ; 
    foreach ($result as $rows ) 
    {
        echo  $rows["Course_name"] . "<br/>" ;
    }
}
echo  table() ;
```

This code does not work and gives these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Now if I use the code like this:

```
function table()
{
    include_once("server.inc");
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $username, $password); 
    $sql="select * FROM d1" ;
    $result = $connect->query($sql) ; 
    foreach ($result as $rows ) 
    {
        echo  $rows["Course_name"] . "<br/>" ;
    }
}
echo  table() ;
```

everything will be alright, but another problem will happen -- I can only use **function table()**  once! If I use it a second time, this error will happen:

> Notice: Undefined variable: servername
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: db
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What shall I do to use my function more than once without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the PDO instance to the function:

```
include_once("server.inc");
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8' , $username, $password); 

function table($connect)
{
    $sql="select * FROM d1" ;
    $result = $connect->query($sql) ; 
    foreach ($result as $rows ) 
    {
        echo  $rows["Course_name"] . "<br/>" ;
    }
}
//echo  table() ;
// Thanks barmar, missed the param before editing!
table($connect); // there's no need to echo the function as it does not return any value, 
                 // the function does the echoing
```

Oh, and you should read the [scoping of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and also the [include vs. include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)